# Form Input and Button not lining up when Zooming in

Tags: html, css

I have a search bar on my website ([link](https://www.talkanxiety.com)), with the form, input and button html markup. The height of the button is less than the input box if the resolution of the screen is not 100% i.e. you can see this by zooming in or out.

Screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/85348ca6a3.js"></script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" class="srchForm" autocomplete="off" style="margin:auto;max-width:480px">
 <input name="msg" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autofocus value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['msg'])) { 
 echo htmlentities ($_POST['msg']); }?>"></input> 
 <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 <input type="submit" style="border:0; padding:0; font-size:0">
</form>

form.srchForm input[type=text] {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  width: 81%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

form.srchForm button {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 3.5%;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bar and the button both have static heights, I would just force that hight to prevent any weird rounding issue:

Add these CSS properties to [your existing CSS rules](https://www.talkanxiety.com/style/style.css):

```css
form.srchForm input[type=text] {
    height: 40px;
}
form.srchForm button {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `flex`. I tested your website it works.

[image]

```css
form.srchForm {
  display:flex;
}

form.srchForm input[type=text] {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  width: 81%;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

form.srchForm button {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 3.5%;
  width: 12%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/85348ca6a3.js"></script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" class="srchForm" autocomplete="off" style="margin:auto;max-width:480px">
 <input name="msg" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autofocus value= "asd"></input> 
 <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
 <input type="submit" style="border:0; padding:0; font-size:0">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Can you tell me why it does work?

Comment: `display: flex` provides a flexible context for all direct children of `form.srchForm`. `flex-direction: row` comes up by default.

Answer (score 1):

If this help, for me when I zoom to 200%+ it lines back up. Your website looks great btw! An helpful.
Also, I kno its kinda hacky but maybe make a horizontal container that's, say, 10% the height of the page, and the make the search bar and button's height 100%.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I want to complete en0ndev's answer and give some explanations. You encountered this problem because you used different font sizes for the items you needed to be displayed in line (while having the same height). You used:

```
form.srchForm input[type=text] {
  font-size: 14px;
}

form.srchForm button {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Even if the font size of the icon is larger than the input's text, the displayed item is smaller (use the same font size for both lowercase and uppercase letters, but the displayed height is different). Because the displayed height difference was small, it was not visible when the page was displayed normally, but when it was magnified, it became obvious. I enlarged the page and increased the font size of the icon button to 28px (when the display: flex was disabled in the form properties). Now the icon's box was bigger.

[image]

When using `display: flex;` on a parent element, all the child elements are displayed in line and stretched to the same height (of the highest element). By default, `display: flex;` includes `align-items: stretch;`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I had the font-size the same for the input and button to start with but they did not line up and that's why I changed the font size of the button until they lined up. That's why I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your font-size to match between the button and the search bar then it will line up.

Comment: Thank you. If I change the font-size of the button and the input to 16px then the height of the button becomes less than the input. Would you be able to advise. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it something to do with fa fa-search and fontawesome?